# Content-disposition inline

Tags: java, excel, internet-explorer-11

In our application we are exporting the excel and we have below code snippet in our code

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=somefile.xsl")
```

Our application only supports in IE, whenever we export the Excel will open in Excel application.

But now the Excel is opening in ie itself instead of Excel application

Answer (score 0):

`inline` means "display inside the Web page" i.e. inside the browser, so if the browser has the capability to do so, it will, and IE can embed Excel "inline".

If you don't want that, use `attachment` instead of `inline`, which generally causes a popup asking whether to save or open in application (e.g. Excel).

Comment: Hi Andreas, we have that inline in our code and it was always ask whether to open or save but it is not working anymore, we have bunch of applications that is using this looking for any other resolution instead of code change

Answer (score 0):

It looks like IE is configured as the default app to open excel file in your system. There's an [**official guide**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/162059/how-to-configure-internet-explorer-to-open-office-documents-in-the-app) to fix this issue, you could try the solutions in it.

Besides, you could check the default apps in your system. You could check these two options in IE:

[image]

Also check the setting **Choose default apps by file type** and make sure to set Excel for .xsl file:

[image]